# перевод миллисекунд в минуты

Tags: java

Здравствуйте! При переводе миллисекунд в минуты, число превышает 60, должно быть меньше 60. Что я делаю не так, подскажите? Спасибо.

```
private String funMinutes(int arg) {
 String str = null;
 if(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(arg) < 10) {
  str = "0" + String.valueOf(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(arg));
 }
 else {
  str = String.valueOf(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(arg));
 }
 return str;
}
```

Comment: С чего взяли, что должно быть меньше 60?

Answer (score 3):

Вот так по симпатичнее будет:

```
private String funMinutes(long arg) {
 return String.format("%02d", TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(arg));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот такой код прекрасно работает:

```
public class mainClass
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        for(long i = 60000; i < 600000; i+=60000)
        System.out.println(funMinutes(i));
    }

    private static String funMinutes(long arg)
    {
        String str = null;
        if (TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(arg) < 10)
        {
            str = "0" + String.valueOf(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(arg));
        }
        else
        {
            str = String.valueOf(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(arg));
        }
        return str;
    }
}
```

Выдает прекрасно:

```
01
02
03
04
05
06
07
08
09
```

Я советую поменять параметр у Вас на long (как сделал я). Прорвете подключение пакетов. Отдебажте код. Чудес не бывает.